# After session.close() connection is still active with Database

Tags: hibernate, dbconnection, hibernate-session

I am working with swing and hibernate.
Now for retrive connection, I am using `sessionFactory.openSession()`. Once I done with DB activity, I am closing same session by `session.close()`.
Now the problem is, when I go on use my application, after some calls, appliation throws exception

```
40503 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=169869568)(ERR=12519)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12519)(EMFI=4))))
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:334)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:418)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
```

While using applicatin, I monitor active DB connections using following query

```
select count(*) from v$session
```

I come to know that connection count is go on increase, and after some connections DB stop giving new ones.

I don't know how to close connections with DB using hibernate as `session.close()` not useful to do so.

Comment: Are you working within a Transactional environment?  Do you call `flush()` on your `Session` before closing it?

Comment: @Mike No. Is it required?

Comment: @Mike, I try with `session.flush()` and `session.clear()`. But same error. One more thing, This exception comes after 15 connections oppened by application.

Comment: It's solved. For solution please refere answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755523/hibernate-connections-are-not-closed-even-with-c3p0-explicit-session-close question.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  I think we are on opposite time zones, so I just got the messages that you left.